# Sitemap are only for "pages"

Tags: sitemap

Does site map only have pages? Does sections, interaction, or links need to be added? I have done a lot of research on site flow and site map. Some examples of sitemaps I've seen includes sections (eg. home pages - has featured items, intro video, and email subscription). Is this the best or better practice of doing sitemaps?

Answer (score 2):

Sitemaps are meant to show the overall structure of a site in order to help figure out what pages are needed and the navigation between them. So create sitemaps that do that, in whatever way is necessary.

Mine show groupings, links to external pages, blobs that represent non-sitemappable features, notes, etc. Whatever helps us understand the scope and structure of what we're designing.